# Realm RealmResults<E> no longer sorts my data in-place

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a `RealmResults<Post> mPosts` object that holds a user's feed in a social media app. Whenever that user used to create new posts, the post would automatically get added to the beginning of the list -- because its date would be the latest and the results were ordered in DESC order. Now, when a user creates a new post, the post is added to the bottom of the list; treated as if it were the oldest post. This just started happening in an older version of `Realm` I had, not sure what it was, but I thought it was a bug so I updated to version 90.0, but it's still happening.

Things I've tried:

- setting `realmResults = realmResults.sort("mDateCreated", Sort.DESCENDING)` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever the user creates a new post
- setting an onChange listener and performing the above statements in the `onChange` method

I've read that RealmResults objects are no longer sorted in-place after after a new updgrade, but after reading several SO, github, and Realm sources, I still can't find any conclusive information on how to imitate the previous sort in-place functionality. Anybody know how to maintain the sorting of a `RealmResults` object in `Realm 90.0`?

**Update**: I've also tried creating my `RealmResults` object using `findAllSorted()` like `RealmResults<Post> mPosts = realm.where(Post.class).findAllSorted("mDateCreated", Sort.DESCENDING)`, and tried it with the things I listed above. Still not working.

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2710 when the first time you create `RealmResults`, create it with `findAllSorted()`. `RealmResults.sort()` will create a new `ReaulResults` and do sort on it.

Comment: forgot to mention it, but i tried that too

Comment: Would you please share some piece of source code related with creating `RealmResults` and listeners?

Comment: @beeender what do you want to see exactly? and i'll get it for you

Comment: @beeender yea, something is definitely wrong with the way realm is sorting objects by date. here's what's happening. i have a bunch of posts sorted by descending order, so the newest post is at the beginning. when i create a new post it goes to the end, after the oldest post. however, when i sort the `RealmResults` object by ascending order like `findAllSorted("mDateCreated", Sort.ASCENDING)`, the posts are displayed in ascending order, but all new posts, instead of going to the end like they did when the results were sorted in descending order, the new post is displayed at the beginning.

Comment: which is the functionality that i want, but not with Sort.ASCENDING set; with Sort.DESCENDING set.

Comment: We made some tests https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2766 , but didn't meet the same problem you met. Can you make a sample project to show the problem and send it to us? to help@realm.io if you want to share it privately.

Comment: @beeender i checked out your tests and i'm having trouble finding where you add new `AllTypes` to the realm after you've initialized the `RealmResults` object

Comment: @beeender solved it beeender. no need to run any more tests. it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I had created a wrapper class for `Post` objects, and I was sorting my `RealmResults mPosts` object by `mDateCreated` in the `PostWrapper` class. So while the dates for the `PostWrapper` records stored on the server were set, and would be used to sort `mPosts` correctly; when they were received from the server and stored in the realm corresponding to `mPosts` -- `UserFeedRealm`. When a user created a new `Post` object on their phone, I was setting the date of the `Post` object, but not the `PostWrapper` object it would be stored in, so because `mDateCreated` was null in the `PostWrapper` object created on the phone, new ones were treated as the oldest `PostWrapper`s in `mPosts`.

The reason the issue seemed like it started in an earlier version of `Realm`, for no reason, was because I implemented reposting functionality in the earlier version, and needed to create a `PostWrapper` class for holding either a `Post` object or a `Repost` object. When I did that, I started storing `PostWrapper` objects in `mPosts` instead of `Post` objects, and starting sorting `mPosts` by the `PostWrapper`'s date created instead of the `Post` object it contained's date created; because a repost would have a different date created compared to the post it's reposting. But I was making a lot of changes at that point, so the effect went unnoticed. But essentially, it all boils down to the fact that I wasn't initializing the necessary variable.